# SQL Report Builder 3- build report from different lists dynamically

Tags: reporting-services, reports

I have an script that automatically creates a SharePoint list for each new `SiteCollection` in my `WebApplication`, so I have many different lists each contains the same columns. The lists name matches to the site collection name: `SCMySite`, `SCDoc`, `SCTest`,...

I want to build a dynamic report in `SQL Report Builder 3` that meets the below requirements:

- The columns will be constant
- The list will be chosen dynamically (all the list contains the same fields).

Can I get the list name from a parameter?

I digged the google and did not find anything.
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I cannot see which version of SharePoint you are using. But you can use rest api for fetching data or SOAP method.

[image]

You can refer to the below Link where you will get all information
http://blog.davidjwise.com/2007/11/28/connecting-sql-reporting-services-to-a-sharepoint-list-redux/

Comment: Please mark it as answer, if it helps you